# What SQL query should I write to copy two dimensional data into table?

Tags: sql-server, django, postgresql

I'm new to SQL and trying to solve this problem. I want to copy this table (attached pic) into the database from csv file. I have created three tables:

1. YEAR Table: I have already inserted years 2014, 2015 and 2016 in it.
2. COMPANY Table: I created two companies 'Alpha' and 'Bravo' in it.
3. FINANCIAL_DATA Table: I have created the revenue and costs categories with Decimal Fields and have put two Foreign Keys one for YEAR table and other for COMPANY table. This data relates to one of the company say 'Alpha' company.

   [image]

What SQL query should I write to copy this data into the FINANCIAL_DATA table? I'm just guessing it will be something like:

```
COPY financial_data (2014, 2015, 2015)
FROM '/Desktop/financial_data.csv'
DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER
WHERE
```

I'm not sure what statement should I write for condition WHERE.

Can you please also confirm if my use of Foreignkey is correct in this case or should I use ManyToMany key or anything else?

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: First decide which rdbms product you use. Mysql, ms sql server and postgresql are all different products. The code in the question is definitely not mysql, so I removed that tag from the list.

Comment: It would require Many-To-Many relationship and it would definitely not be a straightforward csv import. Additionally could you post the Financial_Data table details, what columns do they constitute? Of course before anything as @Shadow mentioned what is the version you are looking for?

Comment: It is postgresql and I have attached the picture of data with this question.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nD2G.png